# Android - RelativeLayout inside a ScrollView doesn't respect its own margin

Tags: android, android-layout, android-scrollview, android-relativelayout

Title says everything.
Here is the xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.myapplication.MainActivity">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:visibility="visible">

        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the screen of design view of the activity

[image]

Here is the screenshot of the running app

[image]

As you can see, in the design view the `RelativeLayout` is in its margin. Instead when the app is running the bottom-right margin are ignored.
This behaviour happens only if the `RelativeLayout` is inside a `ScrollView`

Today I updated Android Studio from version 2.3.2 to 2.3.3. In the previous version this problem wasn't present.

Has anyone had this unexpected behaviour?

Comment: I haven't but what does it do when you give the scrollview the same padding and remove the margin in the layout?

Comment: if I use padding, both in `ScrollView` or in `RelativeLayout`, there is no problem. But I would to know the cause of this issue.